# Angular Canvas only drawing last iteration

Tags: angular, html5-canvas

1. I want to make a chess board with a canvas in angular. But it is only drawing the last iteration.
2. I have tried with the onload function.
3. Here is my code:

   ```
    createBoard(): void {

    let row = 8;
    let col = 8;
    let x = 1;
    let y = 'a';
    let posx = 0;
    let posy = 0;
    let ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

      for(let i = 0; i < row; i++){
        posx = 0;
        for(let j = 0; j < col; j++) {
          let img = new Image();

          img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, posx, posy, 75, 75);
          }

          if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
          {
            img.src = "assets/img/Boardsquare_light_normal.png";
          }
          else
          {
            img.src = "assets/img/Boardsquare_dark_normal.png";
          }
          y = this.nextChar(y);
          posx += 75;
        }
        x += 1;
        y = 'a';
        posy += 75;
      }
   ```

   }

Comment: Try using `ngOnInit` and `ViewChild('canvas',{static:true}) canvas:ElementRef`

Comment: I am already using that

Answer (score 0):

you need two images img1 and img2. As you need the two images are loaded before draw, you can use rxj zip operator and rxjs fromEvent operator

`fromEvent`, is like

```
formEvent(img1,'load').subscribe(_=>{
     ...
})

//its equal than
img1.onLoad=function(){
 ...
}
```

The good of Observables is that you can combining, merge, change... (I know that it's a little hard at first, but a little knowlegde is necessary, remember that in Angular all are Observables)

`zip`, after all observables emit, emit values as an array.

So you can write some like

```
zip([fromEvent(img1,'load'),fromEvent(img2,'load')]).subscribe(_=>{
  for(let i = 0; i < row; i++){
    posx = 0;
    for(let j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
        ctx.drawImage(img1, posx, posy, 75, 75);
      else
        ctx.drawImage(img2, posx, posy, 75, 75);
      posx += 75;
    }
    posy += 75;
  }
})
img1.src='https://picsum.photos/id/100/75/75';
img2.src='https://picsum.photos/id/235/75/75'
```

You can see a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-62nogl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)